# How to copy text to clipboard in Firefox 3.5?

Tags: javascript, firefox

How can you copy text to clipboard **using Javascript** (or even nicer a jQuery function) **without involving Flash**?

I don't care about IE and other browsers; **Firefox 3.5** is the only browser that matters changing local FF settings is OK.

**Edit**:
Sorry for being unclear, I *did* try out the first 30 methods I found via Google; none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [Google search](http://www.google.nl/search?q=firefox+javascript+copy+to+clipboard) resulted in:

- [Enabling Javascript copy-to-clipboard](http://www.febooti.com/support/website-help/website-javascript-copy-clipboard.html)
- MDC: [Using the Clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Clipboard)

Comment: @nh2: Strange, at least the first one worked for me. Just to be sure: did you set `signed.applets.codebase_principal_support` to `true`? But I admit my second answer didn't fit your purposes, as it used flash for FF. I added another link to an MDC component.

Comment: You are right. I accidentally had another key of type string with the same name in my config while the actual correct boolean key was still set to false.

Comment: This once-working way does not work any more. 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/977068#answer-500083 Maybe making some noise in a Firefox bug will help us get a (safe) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will find there are many information if you google it.
eg:
http://www.dynamic-tools.net/toolbox/copyToClipboard/
http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial126_Clipboard-cut-copy-and-paste-with-JavaScript.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the first uses Flash, the second does not work in Firefox 3.

Comment: You can't achieve this without Flash from a web page.

Comment: @David: Yes, you can, look at the second article I linked to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Clipboard

Comment: @Marcel — That looks very much like it only works from Extensions, and not from web pages.

Comment: @David: Nope, the Javascript in the first link in my answer actually uses such a component.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the access to the clipboard by firefox is disabled for security reasons. 
You can edit the setting in firefox to allow it:

In the firefox address bar, type in: "about:config" 
(no quotes), and hit enter.

In the "filter" box you now see, type in the word 
"signed", and you should only have one result coming 
up. It's set to DISABLED. Double-click it, and it 
should change to ENABLED. Close the window. From then 
on, firefox will warn you when a website tries to 
access your clipboard, and you can tell it to "always 
allow this site...."

Answer (score 0):

Now that the problem is solved, I want to add some made-up JavaScript.

- Configure Firefox as described in the accepted answer.

Then use something like this (copied from the Mozilla resource):

```
function copyToClipboard(text) {

// ask for permission to access clipboard

try {
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
} catch(e) {
    alert("Clipboard copying is not allowed. Set signed.applets.codebase_principal_support to 'true' in Mozilla Firefox.");
    return false;
}

// make a copy of the Unicode

var str = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);
if (!str) return false; // couldn't get string obj
str.data = text; // unicode string?


// add Unicode & HTML flavors to the transferable widget

var trans = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransferable);
if (!trans) return false; //no transferable widget found

trans.addDataFlavor("text/unicode");
trans.setTransferData("text/unicode", str, text.length * 2); // *2 because it's unicode 


// copy the transferable widget!

var clipboard = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);
if (!clipboard) return false; // couldn't get the clipboard

clipboard.setData(trans, null, Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard.kGlobalClipboard);
return true;

}
```